# Show a view in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In my controller I have:

```
public function showIndex()
{
    return View::make('index');
}
```

In my views folder I have index.php.

But it's not showing? Where am I going wrong?

I do not wish to use blade templating.

Answer (score 0):

I also had an index.blade.php file in there. It was loading this by default. Deleted the file and now works.